# Place tables always below previous columns

Tags: html

I have two tables in one line - one is on left and second on right. it could be more those two tables and i would like to see always next two tables below previous two. There could be also situation that right table could not appear sometimes. How to make sure two tables or only one (if right one not appears) the next one will be placed below?

This is sample code and screenshoot how it looks at the moment - note that i placed 11 br's between second tables and then it looks ok - but this is not good way as i am not sure how many rows will be for specific tables, so this approach is not correct for sure. Take a look:

```
<br></br>
<table border="3" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10" align="left" style="font-size:12pt;width:30%;">
    <tr>
        <td width="30%" style="vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding-left:20px;color:white;background-color: #778899">Marke::</td><td width="60%" style="text-align:left;padding-left:20px;">JUSThome
        </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td width="30%" style="vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding-left:20px;color:white;background-color: #778899">Serie::</td><td width="60%" style="text-align:left;padding-left:20px;">op
        </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td width="30%" style="vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding-left:20px;color:white;background-color: #778899">Nummer::</td><td width="60%" style="text-align:left;padding-left:20px;">10.1018.1
        </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td width="30%" style="vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding-left:20px;color:white;background-color: #778899">Farbe::</td><td width="60%" style="text-align:left;padding-left:20px;">Zur auswahl
        </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td width="30%" style="vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding-left:20px;color:white;background-color: #778899">Material::</td><td width="60%" style="text-align:left;padding-left:20px;">Ekoleder
        </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td width="30%" style="vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding-left:20px;color:white;background-color: #778899">Material Types::</td><td width="60%" style="text-align:left;padding-left:20px;">Soft
        </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td width="30%" style="vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding-left:20px;color:white;background-color: #778899">Material Attributes::</td><td width="60%" style="text-align:left;padding-left:20px;">Soft 1
        </td>
    </tr>
</table><table border="3" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10" align="right" style="font-size:12pt;width:70%;">
    <tr>
        <td width="30%" style="vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding-left:20px;color:white;background-color: #778899">Hohe::</td><td width="60%" style="text-align:left;padding-left:20px;">1
        </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td width="30%" style="vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding-left:20px;color:white;background-color: #778899">Breite::</td><td width="60%" style="text-align:left;padding-left:20px;">2
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<br></br>
<br></br>
<br></br>
<br></br>
<br></br>
<br></br>
<br></br>
<br></br>
<br></br>
<br></br>
<br></br>

<table border="3" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10" align="left" style="font-size:12pt;width:30%;">
    <tr>
        <td width="30%" style="vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding-left:20px;color:white;background-color: #778899">Marke::</td><td width="60%" style="text-align:left;padding-left:20px;">JUSThome
        </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td width="30%" style="vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding-left:20px;color:white;background-color: #778899">Serie::</td><td width="60%" style="text-align:left;padding-left:20px;">op Farbe: Weiss
        </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td width="30%" style="vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding-left:20px;color:white;background-color: #778899">Nummer::</td><td width="60%" style="text-align:left;padding-left:20px;">10.1018.2
        </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td width="30%" style="vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding-left:20px;color:white;background-color: #778899">Farbe::</td><td width="60%" style="text-align:left;padding-left:20px;">Weiss
        </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td width="30%" style="vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding-left:20px;color:white;background-color: #778899">Material::</td><td width="60%" style="text-align:left;padding-left:20px;">Ekoleder
        </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td width="30%" style="vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding-left:20px;color:white;background-color: #778899">Material Types::</td><td width="60%" style="text-align:left;padding-left:20px;">Soft
        </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td width="30%" style="vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding-left:20px;color:white;background-color: #778899">Material Attributes::</td><td width="60%" style="text-align:left;padding-left:20px;">Soft 1
        </td>
    </tr>
</table><table border="3" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10" align="right" style="font-size:12pt;width:70%;">
    <tr>
        <td width="30%" style="vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding-left:20px;color:white;background-color: #778899">Hohe::</td><td width="60%" style="text-align:left;padding-left:20px;">1
        </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td width="30%" style="vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding-left:20px;color:white;background-color: #778899">Breite::</td><td width="60%" style="text-align:left;padding-left:20px;">2
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**See the screenshoots:**

[Without Br's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRvqd.png)

[With static BR's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFzXz.png)

This code is generated from my code which is Visual Basic code. But maybe with your support we could add some new attributes to my code to handkle that issue. I think its easy to read even if its VB language:

```
  '***************************** FIRST TABLE *****************************

            html.AddStyleAttribute("font-size", "12pt")
            html.AddStyleAttribute(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, "30%")
            'Border
            html.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Border, "3")
            html.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Cellpadding, "10")           'spaces between inner td content
            html.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Cellspacing, "10")           'spaces between td's
            html.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Align, "left")

            html.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Table)                        '---------------------------------------------------------------- TABLE

            For Each item As KeyValuePair(Of String, List(Of String)) In dictionar
                Dim attribute As String = item.Key
                Dim attr_values As List(Of String) = item.Value

                html.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Tr)                           '----------------------------------------------- TR      (row)

                'two below statments will do that text in 1st td will be always on left in the corner
                html.AddStyleAttribute("vertical-align", "top")
                html.AddStyleAttribute("text-align", "left")
                'space from left for text 
                html.AddStyleAttribute("padding-left", "20px")
                'gray background color
                html.AddAttribute("style", "background-color: #778899")
                html.AddAttribute("width", "30%")   'wystarczy dla jednej td, dla prawej nie trzeba
                html.AddStyleAttribute("color", "white")
                html.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Td)                           '--------------------------------- TD               (attribute)       
                html.Write(attribute & ":")
                html.RenderEndTag()                                                 '--------------------------------- /TD               

                'space from left td
                html.AddAttribute("width", "60%")   'wystarczy dla jednej td, dla prawej nie trzeba
                html.AddStyleAttribute("text-align", "left")
                html.AddStyleAttribute("padding-left", "20px")
                html.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Td)                           '--------------------------------- TD               (values)
                For Each sentence In attr_values
                    html.WriteLine(sentence)
                    If attr_values.Count > 1 Then
                        html.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Br)
                        html.RenderEndTag()
                    End If
                Next
                html.RenderEndTag()                                                 '--------------------------------- /TD

                html.RenderEndTag()                                                 '---------------------------------------------- /TR
            Next

            html.RenderEndTag()                                                       '---------------------------------------------------------------- /TABLE

            '***************************** FIRST TABLE *****************************



            '***************************** SECOND TABLE *****************************

            If wymiary.Count > 0 Then

                html.AddStyleAttribute("font-size", "12pt")
                html.AddStyleAttribute(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, "70%")
                'Border
                html.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Border, "3")
                html.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Cellpadding, "10")            'spaces between inner td content
                html.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Cellspacing, "10")            'spaces between td's
                html.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Align, "right")
                html.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Table)                        '---------------------------------------------------------------- TABLE

                For Each item As KeyValuePair(Of String, List(Of String)) In wymiary
                    Dim attribute As String = item.Key
                    Dim attr_values As List(Of String) = item.Value

                    html.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Tr)                           '----------------------------------------------- TR      (row)

                    'two below statments will do that text in 1st td will be always on left in the corner
                    html.AddStyleAttribute("vertical-align", "top")
                    html.AddStyleAttribute("text-align", "left")
                    'space from left for text  
                    html.AddStyleAttribute("padding-left", "20px")
                    'gray background color
                    html.AddAttribute("style", "background-color: #778899")
                    html.AddAttribute("width", "30%")
                    html.AddStyleAttribute("color", "white")
                    html.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Td)                           '--------------------------------- TD               (attribute)       
                    html.Write(attribute & ":")
                    html.RenderEndTag()
                    '--------------------------------- /TD               

                    'space from left td
                    html.AddAttribute("width", "60%")
                    html.AddStyleAttribute("text-align", "left")
                    html.AddStyleAttribute("padding-left", "20px")
                    html.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Td)                           '--------------------------------- TD               (values)
                    For Each sentence In attr_values
                        html.WriteLine(sentence)
                        If attr_values.Count > 1 Then
                            html.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Br)
                            html.RenderEndTag()
                        End If
                    Next
                    html.RenderEndTag()                                                 '--------------------------------- /TD

                    html.RenderEndTag()                                                 '---------------------------------------------- /TR

                Next

                html.RenderEndTag()                                                     '---------------------------------------------------------------- /TABLE
            End If                                              '---------------------------------------------------------------- /TABLE

            '***************************** SECOND TABLE *****************************
```

Comment: Please go to http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid and have a look at the grid system. It should give you what you want. Also you are doing it wrong in HTML. Don't use table attributes but use css styles instead, and DRY.

Comment: @Stephan Zeng hi Stephan - i have to do in this way as this will be placed from external program to some webpage this was requirment. I am looking to do it in the way i do. Can you help?

Comment: do you want something like this https://jsfiddle.net/6hv7u9Ls/??

Comment: yes something really close to that ! maybe with some br between every two tables - as i mentioned i cannot use additional css file - where in my code i have to change something to get as you shown in link? Will it work also when second table for some rows will not be shown?

Comment: if you don't want to use extra file for css then go with Internal/inline css styles to do it and place <br/> or give margin bottom

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/u5058kd7/

Answer (score 0):

Try creating tables using CSS, it's much easier to style them.

You can use the float: left / right to place two tables next to each other (you must set the width of the tables though)

Example:

HTML:

```
<div id="table-left">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">
      Table cell content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="table-right">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">
      Table cell content
    </div>
</div>
```

---

CSS:

```
#table-left {
  display: table;
  width: 49%; /*Change width of table if you want*/
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}
#table-right {
  display: table;
  width: 49%; /*Change width of table if you want*/
  height: auto;
  float: right;
}
.table-row {
  display: table-row;
  width: 100%;
}
.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100px; /*Change width of table cell if you want*/
}
```

---

---

You can change the widths, and add other styles such as background colours and padding all in CSS now, instead of using the messy HTML table markup. You can also add more table cells by placing another table-cell div within the 'table-row' div.

Comment: thanks for your input - sorry i not mentioned but i cannot use external css file as this code is created by external application. Maybe its not html - but ill show you how can i specyfi html attributes and so on from my program maybe based on that we can find out something. See main post